# Final Tkinter window doesn't close when program terminates

Tags: python, tkinter, macos-high-sierra

I am using *Tkinter* to generate a window with a button to close the window and continue the program. However, when the button is pressed, and `top.destroy()` is called, the mainloop ends and the program continues to run, but the window is left behind and the window becomes unresponsive.

The code I'm using is here:

```
from Tkinter import *

top = Tk()
w = Button(top, text="Close", command=top.destroy)
w.pack()
top.mainloop()


print("program ended")
```

[**A screengrab demonstrating the issue**](https://prnt.sc/kbo5lx). Program ended should not display while there is a window present.

What can I do so that the window will close when I press the button when running the program through IDLE?

I am using *IDLE* in *`Python 2.7`* or *`Python 3.6`* (same issue in both), using the *Anaconda installation* of Python, MacOS *High Sierra version 10.13.6*.

Comment: It would seem your code is fine... perhaps your installation is somehow broken? do you have the latest x11 (X Quartz)?

Comment: I didn't have XQuartz installed at the time. I have since installed it, and running the program through it closes the window on button press as intended. This behaviour is also mimicked when running through terminal. However, the problem persists when using IDLE.

Comment: It seems to me like there must be a bug in Cocoa tk/tcl which is why installing XQuartz helped. Further why idle isn't choosing that version over the system built-in is a little strange. What about if you launch idle from terminal with `python -m idlelib`? I also found [this](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) article discussing the issue, but I didn't see anything immediately that should cause your behavior.

Comment: This seems to be a recurring problem a la: https://bugs.python.org/issue10907 It's great that there even is an editor built in to the standard library, but I think it might just be easier to switch to a better editor like spyder or pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two instances of `Tk()`, which you should not.

Other than that; remove the lines:

```
top = Tk()
w = Button(top, text="Close", command=top.destroy)
w.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

and it seems to work fine.

Or did I misunderstand what it is that you want...?

Comment: The second method was there to demonstrate it happens by using tkinter inline or using classes. When root.destroy() is called, the mainloop stops and the program runs, but leaves the tkinter window behind being unresponsive. I'll update the question to be more clear.

Comment: I can not reproduce this. When I click "Close" the window is destroyed and the program resumes printing "program ended". I run Python 3.6.5 under win10.

Comment: It's not easy to search for this issue (hence why I asked here) but I think this is something specifically do with MacOS, I think it's fine on windows/linux, oddly enough.